Opening a chain of links on websites with a browser extension
I'm trying to write a browser extension (for chrome) which queries a specific link on an initial page, opens it, queries a specific link on the new page and opens it again. I managed it to get the first link opened. However, the second link won't be opened. Is it some permission issue or what can I do? Creating browser extensions is very new to me so maybe I'm missing something obvious.
manifest.json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "link opener",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "opens links. I hope?",
    "permissions": [
      "tabs",
      "activeTab",
      "scripting"
    ],
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
  }

popup.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>link opener</title>
  <style>
    body { width: 400px; padding: 20px; }
    #count { font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <span>Links opened</span>
    <span id="count">-</span>
  </div>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


popup.js
function openLinks(){
    const linksA = document.querySelectorAll("li[id='3']");
    for (const linkA of linksA){
      const iconList = linkA.querySelectorAll("i.icon.NextPage");
      if (iconList.length > 0){
        const link = iconList[0].parentElement.href;
        if (link != null){
          var pageA = window.open(link, "_blank");
          const linkB = pageA.document.querySelector("source").src;
          window.open(linkB, "_blank");
          return linkB;
        }
      }
    }
    return "_err";
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, tabs => {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: {tabId: tabs[0].id},
      func: openLinks
    });
  });
});

I was also able to get with only the second part of the code from page A to page B. But as soon as I want to chain it it won't work.
